# how to get a list of layers that are published in geoserver by php?

Tags: javascript, php, gis, openlayers-3, geoserver

I'm using Apache Tomcat 7.0.72 & Geoserver v2.2 & php v5.3.5. i'm going to make a server side app with PHP that controls Accessing the layers that are published with  Geoserver.In viewing the layers from the Geoserver i'm using Openlayers3.i want to have a list of layers that are published in Geoserver. what should i do??!

Comment: You should try it yourself, and review [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why aren't you just using a WMS GetCapabilities request? OpenLayers has `ol.format.WMSCapabilities`, so you can easily get a JSON from the available layers.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', '/geoserver/wms?service=wms&request=GetCapabilities');
xhr.onload = function() {
  var parser = new ol.format.WMSCapabilities();
  var capabilities = parser.read(xhr.responseText);
  var layers = capabilities.Capability.Layer.Layer;
  /* List of layers is now in the `layers` array */
};
```

Comment: Hi ,thank u for your answer.
there is a problem in xhr request and i can't get array (layers)
but that url works for me

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://127.0.0.1:8080/geoserver/wms?service=wms&request=GetCapabilities. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8888' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Please read up on CORS headers to fix this, or make sure your application is hosted under the same domain as your GeoServer.

Comment: My application is on another server becous in this case i need.
but i didn't know what is CORS,i will check it and will say what happen,thanks for ur answer

Comment: excuse me can u help to use CORS. what is that ?
I need to use data from another server.thank u for answers

Comment: i used this code but it dose not have any response?what is problem?
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/geoserver/ows?service=wms&version=1.3.0&request=GetCapabilities');
console.log(xhr);

Comment: Your request url is not valid. Also, you're logging to the console before the request was sent. You need an onload handler and call `xhr.send()`.

Comment: this code work for me but parsing is very hard.
$("#sidemenue").load('http://127.0.0.1:8080/geoserver/wms?service=wms&request=GetCapabilities');